# Google calendar ExtendedProperty filled by user

Tags: vb.net, google-calendar-api

Short question:
I have a google calendar in which the appointments get entered by a vb.net program. I am using the `ExtendedProperty` to fill a value to a variable. But it would be much easier if the google user could fill this value.

Long question: I need to know if this appointment needs further action in the accounting software. So if the user would be able to tell in this google appointment: "Yes, and phone client if order is finished". Then I would be able to find this appointment and take action.
I am using the `newEvent.Content`.`Content` variable for this, but this is errorprone as the user needs to fill in: 
YES#And phone client if order is ready#

```
    Private Function GoogleAgendaAanmaken(ByVal GoogleEmail As String, ByVal GooglePassword As String, _
                         ByVal Titel As String, ByVal Omschr As String, ByVal Locatie As String, _
                         ByVal StartTijd As DateTime) As String

    GoogleAgendaAanmaken = ""
    Dim Id As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

    Try

        Dim serv As CalendarService = GAuthenticate(GoogleEmail, GooglePassword)

        Dim newEvent As New Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry
        newEvent.Title.Text = Titel
        newEvent.Content.Content = Omschr

        Dim Waar As New Google.GData.Extensions.Where()
        Waar.ValueString = Locatie
        newEvent.Locations.Add(Waar)

        Dim newTime As New Google.GData.Extensions.When()
        newTime.StartTime = StartTijd
        newTime.EndTime = DateAdd(DateInterval.Minute, 30, StartTijd)
        newEvent.Times.Add(newTime)

        Dim oExtendedProperty As New ExtendedProperty()
        oExtendedProperty.Name = "SynchronizationID"
        oExtendedProperty.Value = Id
        newEvent.ExtensionElements.Add(oExtendedProperty)

        Dim oExtendedProperty2 As New ExtendedProperty()
        oExtendedProperty2.Name = "Unit4Acties"
        oExtendedProperty2.Value = "JA"
        newEvent.ExtensionElements.Add(oExtendedProperty2)


        Dim newatom As AtomEntry
        Dim uri As New Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/" & GoogleEmail & "/private/full")
        newatom = serv.Insert(uri, newEvent)
        GoogleAgendaAanmaken = Id

    Catch ex As Exception
        Call MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return GoogleAgendaAanmaken

End Function
```

I would like to know if it is possible to change the value of "Unit4Acties" in Google Calendar itself, by the user?

Thanks in advance,
Brian

Comment: have you any code? at present, it is very hard/impossible for anyone to answer this question accurately with only the details you have provided. Remember, we can't see what you have tried, we only can see the details you have posted above!

Answer (score 0):

No, extended properties can only be written to using the API.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid of this. (I can't click the upvote as I don't have 15 reputations, sorry)